# passing URL as args to handler in apps-engine

Tags: python, http, google-app-engine, url, url-parameters

I want to create an apps enginge that get command via url.  How can I acsees the URL from within the handlers?

```
class Handler:
    def get(self):
        url = ? #Here I want to access the url and parse it
        self.response.write(url)

def main():
   application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
           ('/get',   Handler)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm accessing the request URL like this:

```
logging.info('URL: %s' % self.request.path_info)
```

I am using `webapp2`, it's true, but it *should* work with `webapp` as well as `path_info` actually comes from `webob`, which both frameworks are based on.